# Is there a way to host a python function (in azure or elsewhere) with list input/output?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm getting into Azure a little bit, and have been through their tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser). This, however, seems like it's only good for a string query to the HTTPTrigger. I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like:

```
def main(req:HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    input_list = req.params.get("input_list")
    # DO SOMETHING INTERESTING WITH LIST
    output_list = interesting_function(input_list)
    return HttpResponse(output_list)
```

I'm not too familiar with how Azure functions work, or if this is even possible with their framework (or at all anywhere). My idea is hosting a function that I can call from python (as long as I have an internet connection) that will take a list as an input and do some operations on that list, and return it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Functions is a good place to start, though there are other ways. Starting with Azure Functions is fairly easy, which given you mentioned code, I suspect you're after (e.g. Azure Logic Apps can be an alternative, if you prefer Design-driven approach), both are "serverless" (Azure PaaS).

To the other part of your question, taking a "list" - truly the "input binding" is what determines the structure of the request sent. Input mentioned in your message is via an HTTP Trigger, that is someone calls your function and pass something. That argument could be a JSON string, by example, which could have any structure you desire (in this example reading 2 query params and returning them concatenated).

```html
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    category = req.route_params.get('category')
    id = req.route_params.get('id')
    message = f"Category: {category}, ID: {id}"
    return func.HttpResponse(message)
```

All detailed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: So this works if there are only a few parameters in my "list". What if I have, for example, a list of 100 numbers I want to send as my input, would I have to map them each to a keyword as in your example?

Comment: I would suggest passing it a more structured format, e.g. in JSON format, e.g. via POST and read it from BODY. Or, if either of these "numbers" are meant to represent an individual request and be treated in sequence, you could have the function run each instance. You might want to even consider other concepts such as Event Hubs depending on the how fast queries will hit the function, or pushing these into a Queue for post processing securely.